# C# Reading from socket with Stream.Read()

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

I have a simple .net assembly which connects to server and returns opened Stream available for reading and writing. What is important that should be a Stream not a NetworkStream so I don't have a DataAvailable method there.

Now I want to use this simple assembly in console application to communicate with server: sending messages and receive answers through Stream object.

And here is the problem: while reading from socket code below hangs because of Stream.Read() will always wait for input and never return 0.
This behavior described in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958255/what-are-some-reasons-networkstream-read-would-hang-block) topic.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully (Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int read = stream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read <= 0)
                return ms.ToArray();
            ms.Write (buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is from [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html)

Also I can't [set ReadTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097269/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-from-networkstream-in-net) because I only have access to Stream object.

So what can possibly be a solution? How do I read to the whole buffer and determine when to stop?

I was just using a timeout before Stream.Read() but timeouts aren't good.

PS. I am using .net core 1.1 as a target framework, so some solutions requiring .net framework will not work for me.

Comment: And how would you do this if you had NetworkStream instead? The fact that DataAvalilable returns false does not mean some "end" of message is reached.

Comment: Try to make it async

Comment: @Evk Well, at least it helps to stop waiting, and after that people are facing the fact that they really need to wait for the real end of message. I see that one possible solution is implementing a kind of protocol...

Comment: That is what I mean: if you expect to pass several messages (not just one and then close connection) - the only reliable way it to implement a protocol (like first send message length and then message itself).